# Query for retrieving entity by nested foreign reference

Tags: sql, join, foreign-keys

Imagine, you have the following database schema (*FK constraints are omitted; I hope parent->child relationships are obvious for you and can be inferred from the column names*):

```
CREATE TABLE entity (
  ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  NAME VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE property (
  ID   INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  NAME VARCHAR(255)    NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE property_value (
  ID          INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  ENTITY_ID   INT             NOT NULL,
  PROPERTY_ID INT             NOT NULL,
  VALUE       TEXT
);
```

How to fetch **ALL ENTITIES** from the db which match the following sample criteria:

```
propertyName1 = propertyValue1 AND propertyName2 = propertyValue2
OR propertyName3 = propertyValue3
```

More concrete example:

```
Entity entity = new Entity();
entity->setName("t-short")
entity->addProperty("color", "red");
entity->addProperty("time", "14:32");
entity->addProperty("size", "xxl");
```

How to fetch all entities by `color = red AND time > 14:30`

Comment: Can you clarify your AND/OR priority in the condition? Specifically, is it (propertyName1 = propertyValue1 AND propertyName2 = propertyValue2)
OR propertyName3 = propertyValue3     or is it   propertyName1 = propertyValue1 AND (propertyName2 = propertyValue2
OR propertyName3 = propertyValue3) ?

Comment: Can you update your sample criteria to use the table.column names you've provided?

Comment: @TheTTGGuy, it's not important. I need a way to retrieve all entities which match some criteria based on conditions like "name of property" = "some value"

Comment: @WesH, no, because of it is cause of my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT entity.ID
FROM entity
INNER JOIN property_value AS color_value ON color_value.ENTITY_ID = entity.ID 
INNER JOIN property AS color ON color_value.property_id=color.ID
INNER JOIN property_value AS time_value ON time_value .ENTITY_ID = entity.ID 
INNER JOIN property AS time ON time.property_id=color.ID
WHERE time.name="time" AND color.name="color"
AND time_value.VALUE > "14:13" AND color_value = "red"
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have a significant problem with the time filter because you've stored the value as text, which is not time aware.  However, for your color filter, you can do this:

```
select *
from entity as e
join property_value as pv
on e.id = pv.entity_id
join property as p
on p.id = pv.property_id
where p.name = 'color'
and pv.value = 'red'
```

adding additional criteria should be pretty simple:

```
or p.name = 'size'
and pv.value = 'xxl'
```

The issue with the time is that character fields use the character comparison rules, so '2:00' is greater than '14:32', because characters are compared individually and '2' is greater than '1', the placement of the character has no meaning, whereas datetime & number columns use the significance of the digit as part of the comparison (such as the 10s or 100s digits).

'1:' is less then '14' only because ':' is less then '4' in the character code sequence, not because 1 < 14.

Comment: I posted time value just for example. Thank you for explanation